# Mi pregunta es acerca de que problema puede aparecer al definir las columnas de un dataframe como un array o como una lista?

Tags: python

Necesitaba sobreescribir unas filas en un dataframe, inicialmente no le había puesto list() y entonces ocurría que no las sobreescribía, le puse el list y si lo hace bien, sin embargo tengo la duda sobre entonces cual es la forma adecuada de definir y sobreescribir filas en un dataframe y también sobre como se deben definir las columnas asociadas si como arreglos o listas?

```
datosBDSIN.loc[nueva_fila_1, SerPron_cor] = y_corr.loc[indice_1, list(SerPron_cor)]
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué son exactamente (tipo de dato) `SerPron_cor`, `indice_1` y `nueva_fila_1`?

Comment: datosBDSIN es el dataframe, nueva_fila_1 es un entero que será la nueva fila que estoy agregando, SerPron_cor es una lista con 3 columnas que estan en datosBDSIN, e indice_1 es otro indice que recorre el dataframe y_corr buscando las mismas columnas de datosBDSIN

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien lo que significa cada variable, pero respecto a tu pregunta.

Lo correcto es introducir filas como listas (han de tener el mismo número de datos que columnas tiene el Dataframe). Te pongo un ejemplo sencillo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

df.iloc[1] = ['hola', 'tia', 'mari']
```

```
      0    1     2
0     1    2     3
1  hola  tia  mari
2     7    8     9
```

Espero haberte ayudado :)